# Mouse Randomly Scrolls Backwards Despite Repairs

Tags: mouse, scrolling, repair

I have a wireless mouse I bought in 2014. For 4 years I had no issues with the scroll wheel, and then it started to randomly send backwards scrolls sometimes, along with the proper ones. I cleaned it, and it was good for a little while. I took apart the encoder wheel inside ([it's this type of mechanism](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/5PCS-Mouse-Encoder-Wheel-Encoder-Repair-Parts-Switch-11mm-IL/400945913178)) cleaned it thoroughly, and again it was good for a little while. Then I purchased brand new encoder wheels and soldered on a brand new one. It was good as new, but again SOMEHOW it didn't last! At this point I'm beyond comprehension how this is even possible.

I highly doubt the issue is actually dust buildup, since it took the mouse four years to start malfunctioning, and now it's just two weeks after installing a brand new encoder wheel, and a day or two after blowing into it. I know it's not the batteries, since I've changed those since the issues have started, and it's not a specific computer, since I use it on multiple computers and it behaves the same way.

What could this be? Any ideas for things I can look at to replace/clean/cover?

Comment: The fact that cleaning resolves the issue, even if only briefly indicates to me that the issue is likely dust/dirt/debris buildup.

Comment: To test once and for all if dust is actually the issue, I wrapped the encoder wheel in a piece of plastic from a sandwich bag and fastened it on with some string. If the problem persists even though the encoder wheel is completely protected from dust, then we know that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connections from wheel encoder to PCB. Likely, years of use has caused a soldered connection or a copper trace to break. Moving the innards and reassembling them brings the parts into contact temporarily until further use breaks contact again.

If the PCB is one layer, single or double sided, the connection can simply be resoldered. If the PCB is multilayer, you may need to find the endpoint of the broken connection and install a small jumper of fine wire.

Comment: Like I said, I have resoldered on a brand new encoder wheel, and the solder joint is fine, making full contact on both sides. The problem was resolved, but it only lasted for 2-3 weeks.